# Mac OS X disk performance monitoring

Tags: macos, performance

Which tools to use for detailed performance analysis of disk access?

- per disk
- per process
- queues
- latency
- data volume/throughput
- errors
- characterisation (read Vs write, burst, etc.)

Tried iostat, iopending, could use a syste

Comment: Have you tried "Activity Monitor"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instruments (which is part of Xcode) and dtrace are the heavy hitting analytical tools for most disk measurement jobs. Both are free and both take a little training to use unless you find someone to set up your traces for you to match your above criteria.

Look for errors in system.log or the console app.